# Language Identities Prove/Disprove

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Problem:**

**Prove/disprove the following identity on languages A, B, C:  A(B ∪ C) = AC ∪ BC**

I worked it out to where A(B U C) = AB U AC by the distributive property...

but I can't reason how that ends up at AC U BC... I can see how AC U BC = (A U B)C, maybe the union associative?

Then I could see how A(B U C) = (A U B)C - but I don't think this works... I tried using mock sets where A = {a,b}, B = {c,d}, and C = {e,f}, but I get different results for the original equation.

A(B U C) = {ac, ad, ae, af, bc, bd, be, bf} and AC U BC = {ae, af, be, bf, ce, cf, de, df}

Thanks in advance - sorry if my formatting isn't up to par - this is my first question on this site.

Comment: The fact that the identity is sometimes false (as your counterexample shows) is a very good excuse for being unable to prove it.

Comment: You could, however, be more efficient with your counterexample: Take $C$ to be empty and take $A$ and $B$ to be one-element sets.

Comment: I thnk I see what you mean there. The question is presented as proove/disprove - I'll edit that part. I am thinking this counter example disproves the proposition but I don't know if I've explored enough options or if my counterexample is wrong.

Comment: Your counterexample is fine and it disproves the identity.

Comment: Ah, much appreciated - thank you!

Comment: @jRod whenever you're trying to prove anything, a single counterexample is always enough to show it is not possible to give a proof